# O que é reatividade no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, react, programação-reativa

Eu vejo em *frameworks* como Angular, Vue, React, o conceito de **reatividade**.

Eu sou totalmente leigo no assunto, e pelo pouco que sei, o conceito de programação reativa é basicamente a realização de fluxo de dados assíncronos. Uma variável em algum desses *frameworks* que citei, acaba sendo reativo, porque conforme você atualiza no controller/componente, ele altera no DOM.

Mas como isso realmente funciona? Eu inseri um *snippet* de como eu imagino um *observable* funcionando, seria algo desse tipo que consiste reatividade?

```js
var variavel = 1

function observable (){
 setInterval(function(){
  if(variavel == 1){
     console.log('Do Nothing...')
    } else console.log('Mudou!')
 }, 1000)
}

function Usuario(){
setInterval(function(){
 console.log('Usuario fez alguma ação que mudou a variavel')
 variavel = 2
}, 5000)
}

Usuario()
observable()
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo Edit, @Stormwind

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A maneira que usaste não é reactiva, é tipo pooling, ir procurando por mudanças e isso não escala, ou seja é muito pesado estar a re-ler e comparar valores em intervalos de tempo pequenos.

O conceito de reactividade baseia-se na capacidade de uma variável avisar que foi mudada. Contruindo uma cadeia de reações, um fluxo no código (como disseste: *"fluxo de dados assíncronos"*),  é possível que mudando uma variável a mudança se propague tornando a aplicação reactiva.

Um exemplo arcaico de reactividade seria assim:

```js
const callbacks = {};

const VARS = {
  _foo: new Date(), // valor inicial
  get foo() {
    return this._variavel;
  },
  set foo(val) {
    this._foo = val;
    callbacks.foo.forEach(fn => fn(val));
  }
}

function observable(prop, fn) {
  if (!callbacks[prop]) callbacks[prop] = [];
  callbacks[prop].push(fn);
}

observable('foo', function(novoValor) {
  console.log('Mudou observador 1!', novoValor);
});
observable('foo', function(novoValor) {
  console.log('Mudou observador 2!', novoValor);
});


console.log('À espera...');
setInterval(function() {
  console.log('Usuario fez alguma ação que mudou a variavel')
  VARS.foo = new Date();
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Muito bem explicado! Obrigado @Sergio :) !!